# How to delete dataframe line index?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading an excel file with pandas.read_excel function. In this excel file, the first column is called "Date". 
It has only dates but when I print "Date" column or send the dataframe to a file it insert the line index.
Look below:

```
0     2019-01-11
84    2019-01-11
126   2019-01-11
147   2019-01-11
63    2019-01-11
168   2019-01-11
```

I do not want the index numbers(i.e: 0, 84, 126...) to be printed or added in my CSV/excel file. How can I remove them?

Thank you!

Comment: use `df.to_csv(file.csv,index=False)`

Comment: ...or to print values of the column only you could try `print(df.Date.values)`

Comment: Thank you very much Anky! It has solved my problem. Is there some way to print without index in python?

Comment: `print(df.to_string(index=False))`

Comment: Thank you for your super fast help Anky. This question is now solved.